# Is HashMap and Adjacency Lists(used to represent graph) are same?

Tags: c

I am trying to understand Hash-Map and an Adjacency List. Are they both same in terms of how they are implemented?

Comment: No, they are completely unrelated. They are implemented differently, and they solve different problems. Where did you get the idea they are similar?

Comment: Since Hash Map can be implemented using Adjacency list. I thought both are same in terms of implementation.

Comment: It's the other way around, you can implement an adjacency list using a hash map. So a hash map is a basic data structure, and you use it to build other more complex structures, but an adjacency list is usually implemented using a *linked list* (hence the name). And even in the "common" case, it would be wrong to say that an adjacency list and a linked list are the same thing (or to say that "dynamic programming and arrays are the same thing" because you use arrays for solving DP problems -- it just doesn't make sense).